# Iniciar IndexPath desde uno

Tags: swift, xcode

Necesito iniciarlo desde el uno para que muestre los datos correspondientes de la BD

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    vcName = values[indexPath.row]["idCategoria"] as! String
    print(vcName)
    //performSegueWithIdentifier("show", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if (segue.identifier == "show") {

        if let vc: ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController {
            vc.idCategoria = vcName
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No és posible iniciarlo desde 1, ya que no debe ser así. Antes de aplicar la solución que te daré, yo revisaría la base de datos, porque como todo en programación, lo ideal es que empiece desde cero.

Aún así, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
vcName = values[indexPath.row + 1]["idCategoria"] as! String
```

Recuerda, que si tienes 10 filas, con el método que te he pasado, el rango ya no será 0-9 sino que pasará a ser 1-10 y puede que la aplicación pete al acceder a un índice que no existe.

Comment: Ya intente eso y tienes razón que peta la aplicación, solo el problema es con la primer celda que empieza del cero y no manda el id para mostrar los datos todos los demás si

Comment: Pues entonces, coge el "idCategoria" y súmale 1. Sino, rehaz la base de datos para que empiece desde cero.